# Не было ни секунды, чтобы я не подумала о тебе

Tags: синтаксис, союзы

> *Не было ни секунды, **чтобы я не подумала о тебе**.*

Можно сказать, что *чтобы я не подумала о тебе* предложение относительное, вводимое через *чтобы*? Никогда не видела до сего дня, что относительное придаточное может вводится через этот союз, поэтому очень сомневаюсь. Или это союз *что*, который слился с частицей *бы*, потому что глагол в сослагательном наклонении?

Большое спасибо!

Comment: shampar: thank you very much, I'll correct it immediately =)

Answer (score 1):

Говоря об **относительном** предложении, Вы имеете в виду ***относительное местоимение*** как средство связи? В синтаксисе русского языка нет такого термина, мы говорим о *связи с помощью союза и союзного слова* (местоимения и местоимённого наречия).

Это разговорная конструкция, *чтобы* употреблено вместо *в которую*.

Не было ни секунды, *в которую* не подумала *бы* о тебе. Так что здесь союз синонимичен союзному слову-относительному местоимению  (чтобы = в которую =    когда): *Не было ни секунды, когда бы я не подумала о тебе.*

Второй Ваш вариант тоже **по смыслу**  достаточно верно показал картину.Можно сказать и о союзном слове *что=который,* только придётся чуть перестроить:

*Не было такой  секунды, что я не думала бы о тебе.*

Союз ***чтобы***  иногда вносит целевой оттенок: Н*е было у меня такого уговору, чтобы дрова таскать (М. Г.)*. Преобладание определительного значения в придаточной части подчеркивается местоимением такого, без которого изъяснительное значение стало бы основным (уговор о чём?).

В Вашем примере *чтобы* вносит не целевой оттенок, а значение ирреальности, сослагательности, следовательно, можно говорить о слиянии *что* и *бы*

Comment: *Говоря об относительном предложении, Вы имеете в виду относительное местоимение как средство связи?* -  Людмила, ну что вы... Имелось в виду "придаточное относительное". Термин вполне устоявшийся. http://rusgram.ru/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5

Comment: Устоявшийся-то устоявшееся, но многое в себя включает, в том числе и придаточное определительное, и местоимённо-определительное, я хотела выяснить, о чём здесь речь, чтобы ответить, можно ли его назвать относительным.

Answer (score 0):

**Не было ни секунды, чтобы я не подумала о тебе.**

**Это СПП с местоименно-союзной (соотносительной) связью, причем особый подтип с отрицанием в главной части.**

Рассмотрим варианты такого предложения:

Не было **такой секунды, в которую**  я не подумала бы  о тебе.

Не было **такой секунды, чтобы**  я не подумала   о тебе.

Таким образом, используя союз ЧТОБЫ, мы переходим от чисто местоименной связи с помощью союзного слова КОТОРЫЙ (и сослагательного наклонения глагола)  к местоименно-союзной связи с помощью ирреального союза ЧТОБЫ.

Характерной особенностью предложений с местоименно-союзной связью является то, что признак предмета в главном предложении описывается не через местоименную связь "указательное слово-союзное слово", а через ситуацию в придаточном предложении.

**Предложения похожей структуры:**

Не такой туман, чтобы отменять полеты. Я не так уверен в своих выводах, чтобы говорить о них. Я не так воспитан, чтобы подслушивать.

Примеры с другими союзами или с союзом ЧТОБЫ без отрицания:

День **такой** холодный, **что** не хочется выходить из дома. У него **такой** вид, **словно** он трое суток не спал. Он стремился создать такую атмосферу, **чтобы** дети чувствовали себя как дома.

Answer (score -1):

> Можно сказать, что чтобы я не подумала о тебе предложение
>   относительное, вводимое через чтобы?

В каком-то смысле - можно. "Чтобы" здесь выступает синонимом "в котором", "за который". А точного списка союзов, присоединяющих относительные предложения не существует, как и самого четкого определения, что считать в русском относительным предложением. 
Тут другое сомнительно. Вершиной относительного предложения приходится считать конструкцию "ни секунды" - вот тут я сомневаюсь...

Подробности - тут.
http://rusgram.ru/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5

> Или это союз что, который слился с частицей бы,

А почему "или"? Это тоже верно.

> потому что глагол в сослагательном наклонении?

Ну во-первых, вы путаете причину со следствием. Форма глагола выбирается под тип предлложения, а не наоборот. А во-вторых... Ну забудьте вы про это сослагательное наклонение уже. Несколько раз говорил, что в русском нет жесткого соответствия ситнаксической формы и семантики.
А том что это за предложение в классической подходе лучше всего рассказывает  Людмила, я не буду её мешать.

(++++++++)
Если не секрет, по каким учебникам вы всё это изучаете? Эти темы (относительное предложение, сослагательное в таком объеме и проч.) явно не из обычного курса русского как иностранного. Это отдельное направление изучения, другая школа, чем-то близкое компративизму - через сравнение грамматик разных языков. Поэтому всё, что сказано в других ответах (Людмилой особенно) никак не противоречит тому, что сказал я. Это просто другая, параллельная систематика.

Заодно. По поводу правки "до сегодня" на "до сего дня". "До сегодня" и подобные конструкции уже прочно проникли в разговорный язык. Это не ошибка, хотя лично я тоже по-прежнему предпочитаю классический вариант "до сего дня".

(---)

Вот еще ссылка на конкретную тему. Здесь раскрываются и причины, по которым отнесение подобных предложений к относительным не общеприняты.
http://rusgram.ru/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5#821